# Hexadecimal Memory Address to Assembly

Tags: python, terminal, hex, memory-address, buffer-overflow

I am following a buffer overflow tutorial. I have set up my NOP block, I also set up my shell code, now I need to append the return address to the end of my string. I know my return address is :

`0xbfffef40`

however I need to write it in the form:

`xd0\xce\xff\xff` (that's just an example address to show what format I need)

I'm not sure how to carry out the conversion between the two.

Comment: See `struct.pack`.

Comment: Could you show the same number (so we know if you need big or little endian) ?

Comment: @enrico.bacis not sure what you mean, its a ubuntu 32 bit distribution that I'm running this on. I can't show the same address because I need the conversion, thats what the question is about

Comment: @MarkTolonen using struct.pack("!I", 0xbffef40) I obtain '\xbf\xff\xef@' is this correct?

Comment: Probably not.  Most systems are little-endian so you'll want `'<L'`, or just `'L'` which uses the default endian-ness of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) like this:

```
import struct
struct.pack('<L', 0xbfffef40)
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) of `struct.pack` if you want to change the endianness.